# Demo griddb help required and SQL queries are not working

Tags: sql, griddb

I'm currently exploring the GridDB demo and attempting to utilize the SQL capabilities mentioned in the documentation  https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_5/GridDB_SQL_Reference.html#sql-description-format, That we can use SQL things.

However, I have encountered an error while executing a query, and I'm seeking assistance to resolve the issue.

Here is the error message I received:
[image]

I would greatly appreciate any references, links, or solutions that can help me troubleshoot and overcome this error. Additionally, if anyone has experience with GridDB and its SQL functionality, I would appreciate any insights or recommendations for resolving this issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be that you're trying to create a new database but lack the proper permissions (you're not an admin). Though I will say, you do not need to be making a new database on the GridDB Cloudshell as each session generates a new database per user (the DB name is within the gs[pXXXX] line)